# Hide/Show Button based on status if row selected - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I hope I can be of help. I could not find anything like this in javascript.
I did in C # code, but I could use in Javascript for faster page and related transactions.

My situation is this: 
I have to hide or display two buttons depending on the choice of a selected line taking into account the value of a particular field.

How to bring it in Javascript?

For now I've done this:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        function cbCheck_CheckedChanged()
        {     
  List<object> ListStatoIns = new List<object>();
            try
            {
                if (ListStatoIns != null)
                {
                    if (ListStatoIns.Exists(x => x.Equals(true)) && ListStatoIns.Exists(x => x.Equals(false)))
                    {
                        btnApriInserimenti.style.display = "block";
                        btnChiudiInserimenti.style.display = "block";
                    }

                    else if (!ListStatoIns.Exists(x => x.Equals(true)))
                    {
                        btnChiudiInserimenti.style.display = "none";
                        btnChiudiInserimenti.style.display = "block";
                    }

                    else if (!ListStatoIns.Exists(x => x.Equals(false)))
                    {
                        btnChiudiInserimenti.style.display = "block";
                        btnChiudiInserimenti.style.display = "none";
                    }
                }
            }

            catch (err) {  }

      
        }
    </script>
```

This is Grid:

```html
 <cap:MultiColumnSortingGridView ID="gvDettaglio" runat="server" CssClass="grid-view"
                                DataKeyNames="Organizzazione,OrgID,Mensilita,CodiceOrg,isCaricamentoCompletato" 
                                EmptyDataText="Non sono presenti dati inspezionabili: controlla la mensilità di riferimento o lo stato della contabilità" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                                ExportButtonCssClass="button BtnExportExcel" ExportFileName="Dettaglio Straordinario">
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="40">
                                        <HeaderTemplate>
                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="cbCheckAll" runat="server" Checked="false" />
                                        </HeaderTemplate>
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="cbCheck" runat="server" CssClass='<%# Eval("isCaricamentoCompletato")%>'
                                                ToolTip="Seleziona per la riapertura o la chiusura dell'inserimento" 
                                                AutoPostBack="true" onclick="javascript:gvDettaglio.Rows(cbCheck_CheckedChanged);"/>                                                
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="40">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <span class="jTooltipR button BtnAudit" title='<%# PrintOperazione(Eval("_ultimo"), Eval("_ultima")) %>'></span>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Mensilita di pagamento">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <%# PrintMensilita(CNA.CommonLib.Util.ConversionUtil.ConvertInt32orDefault(Eval("Mensilita"))) %>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CodiceOrg" HeaderText="Codice" SortExpression="CodiceOrg" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="OrgID" HeaderText="Id Org." Visible="false" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Organizzazione" HeaderText="Organizzazione" SortExpression="Organizzazione" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="NrDipendenti" HeaderText="Militari al BTG/RGT" SortExpression="NrDipendenti" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="NrDipInteressati" HeaderText="Mil. con Str." SortExpression="NrDipInteressati" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="NrJobMassivi" HeaderText="File inseriti" SortExpression="NrJobMassivi" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="NrJobElaborazioni" HeaderText="Militari inseriti" SortExpression="NrJobElaborazioni" />
                                    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="20">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <span class="jTooltipL buttonLittle BtnInfoLittle" title='<%# PrintTotaleDet(Eval("Totale")) %>' />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Totale Ore">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <%# PrintTotale(Eval("Totale")) %>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Stato Inserimento" SortExpression="isCaricamentoCompletato">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <label class='<%# Eval("isCaricamentoCompletato").Equals(true) ? "validatedNotItem" : "validatedItem"%>'
                                                style="width: 40px!important;"
                                                title='<%#Eval("isCaricamentoCompletato").Equals(true) ? "Caricamento Chiuso" : "Caricamento Aperto"%>'>
                                            </label>
                                            <%--<span class="jTooltipL buttonLittle BtnInfoLittle" title= '<%#Eval("isCaricamentoCompletato").Equals(true) ? "Caricamento Chiuso" : "Caricamento Aperto"%>' />--%>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="40" HeaderText="Dettaglio">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:LinkButton CausesValidation="false" ID="btnExportExcel" runat="server"
                                                CssClass="button BtnExportExcel" Width="40" CommandName="Report" OnClick="OnClikDettaglioStraordinario"
                                                Visible='<%# !String.IsNullOrEmpty(PrintTotale(Eval("Totale"))) %>'
                                                ToolTip='Dettaglio straordinari inseriti' />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                </Columns>
                            </cap:MultiColumnSortingGridView>
```

Who helps me? many thanks in advance